# VBA selective hardcoding / Paste values if string in cell matches specific string

Tags: string, vba, hardcode

First time posting for me and hoping to get some help with VBA for selective hardcoding.

I currently have a column into which a formula is set which returns either blank or a variety of text strings (the status of our company's orders).

I need to make a macro that looks into all the cells of that column and copy/pastes as value into that same cell only if the formula in that cell returns text string "Received". It should not affect the other cells where the formula is returning either blank or a different text string.

Would really appreciate your help. Please let me know if you need more info.

Thanks in advance,

Olivier

Comment: To clarify - scan a range of cells. If the formula in that cell returns "Received", replace the formula with the string. Did I understand correctly? Is the range always the same?

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in the VBA project of your workbook:

```
Option Compare Text

Sub replaceThem()
Dim r As Range
Dim c

Set r = Range("B1:B3") ' use the actual range here
For Each c In r
  If c.Value = "Received" Then c.Formula = "Received"
Next

End Sub
```

This will do what you asked. `c.Value` returns the value of the formula in the cell `c`, `c.Formula` replaces the formula. The `Option Compare Text` makes the comparison case-insensitive.

Comment: Sorry for ridiculously late answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello! That must be a record delay from answer to first reaction... for me anyways.